# Creating a listView refreshable

Tags: android

I want to create a listView with items from another listView. I have a page and one button. When I press the button, I want to open a list. When I click an item from that list I want to populate the first page (with the button that I press) with that item selected and to make refresh at the list that I want to create. Also I want to store the list created (with items selected) in a table. Can someone help me with some tutorial? I searched a lot but I didn't find something that can help me to resolve this.I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tutorial for how to work with list views in android:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

for refreshing your data, just put your new data and use `notifyDataSetChanged` on your list adapter